# connecting Xamarin database

Tags: azure, xamarin

Hi i am just wondering is this how you connecting to an azure database I am building an Xamarin application and was wondering is this correct or should the login and password be there too?

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 Uri uri = new Uri("AzureDatabaseName.database.windows.net");
```

Thanks for your help and if its incorrect any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DylanS he might be using Azure Document DB, or any other database server Azure can host, which can be anything microsoft or 3rdparty.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin and Azure there are actual components that you need to use for Azure mobile services. Check Xamarin's guide on their website, is pretty straightforward.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/mobile-apps/

Hope this helps.